# нормальный закон распределния

Tags: c, математика, случайные-числа

Нужно перейти от равномерного закона (насколько я знаю , в рандоме он такой) к Гауссовскому закону(нормальному закону) распределения.
Желательно ещё как-то вывести полученные результаты.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE_ARRAY 20
void support(int chislo,int stroka)
{
char simvol='=';
 int i=0;
    printf("%d:",stroka);
    do{
        i++;
        printf("%c",simvol);
    }while(i<chislo);
        printf("%d\n",chislo);
}

int main()
{
    int j=0;
    int a[SIZE_ARRAY] = {0};
    int x=0;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    do
        {
        x=rand()%SIZE_ARRAY;
        a[x]++;
        j++;
    }while(j<50*SIZE_ARRAY);
    int p=0;
    for(p;p<SIZE_ARRAY;p++)
    {
        support(a[p],p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/208684/

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примените [преобразование Бокса-Мюллера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0).

```
double f = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX;
double r = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX;

r = sqrt(-2*log(r));
double x = cos(2*PI*f)*r;
double y = sin(2*PI*f)*r;
```

`x` и `y` независимы и имеют нормальное распределение с матожиданием 0 и дисперсией 1. К другим параметрам легко привести сдвигом и масштабированием.

Comment: насколько я понимаю это просто отдельная функция . А как сделать чтобы она брала значения от моей функции ?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, даже не понял вопрос... У вас я никакой функции - кроме `main` - не вижу.

Comment: Добавил полностью программ.

Comment: Согласно предельной теореме, сумма случайных величин стремится к нормальному распределению. Так что ответ является ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вот метод, обсуждаемый у Кнута, из часто задаваемых вопросов по Си — [c.l.c faq-13.20](http://c-faq.com/lib/gaussian.html):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double gaussrand()
{
    static double V1, V2, S;
    static int phase = 0;
    double X;

    if(phase == 0) {
        do {
            double U1 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            double U2 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

            V1 = 2 * U1 - 1;
            V2 = 2 * U2 - 1;
            S = V1 * V1 + V2 * V2;
            } while(S >= 1 || S == 0);

        X = V1 * sqrt(-2 * log(S) / S);
    } else
        X = V2 * sqrt(-2 * log(S) / S);

    phase = 1 - phase;

    return X;
}
```

See also [Ziggurat algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm)